# Need to get the Search response time

Tags: solr, content-search

I need to get the time taken for each response time for each search that we are making from the Sitecore. I've tried changing the log configuration of Search Log to Debug mode but the log doesn't have time on that.

Is there any way to get the timing of each quey?

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <!--  VERBOSE LOGGING
             This feature is designed to facilitate search index configuration and provide the necessary insight
             in troubleshooting scenarios. For example, if a particular item is not getting indexed,
             the VerboseLogger can provide more context and help you to figure out the problem.

             It is important that you only enable the VerboseLogger component in special circumstances
             and never run it for long periods in a production environment.
             Otherwise, this would result in an extremely large log file, which may have performance implications.
       -->
      <setting name="ContentSearch.VerboseLogging" value="true" />
    </settings>
    <log4net>
      <logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Search" additivity="false" >
        <appender-ref ref="SearchLogFileAppender"/>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
      </logger>
      <logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Crawling">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
      </logger>
    </log4net>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you intend to use this information?

Comment: One of our client is planning to move from on premises of Solr server to Solr cloud with Master and Slave configurations. So they need to know the before and after to Solr cloud on performance.

Comment: Then reading the log files may not be the way to go. Consider using load testing tools that can simulate the traffic.

Comment: Thanks @michael sure we’ll use the load test for measuring the performance and apart form load test is there any other way can we get the information?

Comment: https://github.com/tflobbe/solrmeter/blob/wiki/about.md

Comment: @x3mxray Thanks for the link. Sure I'll try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable Solr logging either via [Solr admin console](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/configuring-logging.html#ConfiguringLogging-TemporaryLoggingSettings) or [via startup setting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/configuring-logging.html#ConfiguringLogging-ChoosingLogLevelatStartup)
2. Restart Solr service if you changed startup setting
3. Run something on Sitecore to fill log. (As Michael West mentioned in comments, you may consider load testing tools to simulate traffic)
4. Open \server\logs folder under Solr installation location
5. Open recent log file

Log file will contain all queries and execution time (QTime).

Comment: Yes after some research we came to know the same and we implemented. And yes it worked. Thanks for your comment.